# c# How do you check whether opposite textbox is not null if the first one is filled

Tags: c#, foreach, textbox, groupbox

[image]

I have several textboxes, what I need is to check whether textbox in groupbox 2 has been filled with values if the opposite textbox in groupbox1 has any values.

I have started with the following code yet I am confused because foreach gets only value for groupbox2 and its actually difficult for me since they are not linked together

```
        foreach (TextBox box in groupbox2.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
        {

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(//GROUPBOX 1 TEXT BOX GOES HERE))
            {

                box.Text = "This needs filling";
                break;
            }
        }
```

I was thinking of using indexes but not sure how to implement them

Comment: One problem is that your validation loop depends on each control's position in the Controls collection (biz/code logic working depends on a UI thing).  You could use a dictionary or look up one thing from the other

Comment: You might consider creating a class that represents the state of all your textboxes, and update properties of this class in the `TextChanged` event of each textbox. That way you don't have to do any looping through controls later, you just query your state object.

Comment: @RufusL: I concur. As a general rule, trying to access the GUI to get data is a bad approach. It is better to always have the data in the backend.